# Image is going out of the parent div if the page is zoomed

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, cdn

I tried positioning the div elements but couldn't achieve what I wanted.

```css
.tab-vertical {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="tab-vertical">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab3" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="vertical-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="" role="tab" aria-controls="Notes" value="A" onclick="javascript:void()" aria-selected="true">
        <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/512/200/png-transparent-iphone-4s-desktop-baby-blocks-android-abc-game-photography-toy-block.png" alt="Notes" style="width: 23px; height: 20px; margin:2px 0px 3px 3px;">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit and add relevant CSS and frameworks in a [mcve]. Add images from lorempixel or similar

Comment: The image in your snippet doesn't show, and your snippet doesn't really show the issue you are describing. I recommend using https://picsum.photos/ to use a random photo for your example

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem in the snippet I made you here

Comment: I am using this platform for the first time, so i just added the code snippet, but dono how do i write a reproducible issue.Please guide

Comment: To begin with, please explain exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: [edit], scroll down, click "edit above snippet", add frameworks like bootstrap and other CSS in the relevant panes. As you can see I added a border to your div to see if that would show the issue but it did not

Comment: You probably shouldn't have an onclick attribute on your tab anchor. That's generally bad practice and isn't needed. See the [tab docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navs/#tabs).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tab-vertical {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex; 
  align-items: flex-start; /* Align items at the top */
}

.tab-vertical .nav-tabs {
  flex-direction: column; /* Arrange tabs vertically */
}

.tab-icon {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
}

.tab-icon img {
  width: 23px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 2px 0px 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-vertical">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab3" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="vertical-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-content" role="tab" aria-controls="Notes" aria-selected="true">
        <div class="tab-icon">
          <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/512/200/png-transparent-iphone-4s-desktop-baby-blocks-android-abc-game-photography-toy-block.png" alt="Notes">
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content">
    <!-- Tab content goes here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With these changes your vertical tabs will properly align with the image within each tab. And the problem is this "Image is going out of the parent div if the page is zoomed" asked by the person.

Comment: Well, all the flex stuff seems unnecessary, and Bootstrap has classes for all that anyway. I think the only thing needed is the margin on the image.